# Selecting rows in R based on threshold

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, subset

In R, I have a matrix with N columns of all numbers.  (Each row has a name, but that's irrelevant.)  I'd like to return rows where there is at least one column has a value greater than some threshold.  Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
THRESHOLD <- 10
#  my_matrix[,1] can be ignored
my_matrix <- subset (my_matrix, my_matrix[,1] > THRESHOLD | my_matrix[,2] > THRESHOLD | ... )
```

It seems odd to have to manually list each column.  Also, if the number of input columns changes, I have to rewrite this.

There has to be a better way, but I can't figure out what I should be looking for.

I can convert my matrix to a data frame, if that is easier...  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: please show a reproducible example including expected output.

Comment: `mat[apply( mat[, 2:ncol(mat)], 1, function( x ) any( x > threshold ) ), ]`  mat is your matrix data

Comment: `my_matrix[apply(as.matrix(my_matrix[-1,])>THRESHOLD, 1, any),]`

Comment: A matrix can hold numerics xor characters but not both. What does it mean *first column are strings but the other columns are numbers*: the first column are the rownames or your numbers are stored as character, e.g. "3.14". Please edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42945642/edit

Comment: @Sathish Thanks for that; I'll give it a try.  Feel free to post a solution so that I can accept it.  As it turns out, I did not know "apply" could be used that way.  That was what I was looking for...

Comment: @jogo I think what I said in my original question is correct.  That is, "I'd like to return rows where there is at least one column (i.e., exclude the first column)".  I'm not sure how can I say that any better...

Comment: @jogo Ah!  You are correct about one thing, though.  I did make a mistake in my "sample code".  If the first column are names, then I should start my subset () statement from 2 and not 1.  I've just fixed that...sorry for the contradiction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find any row values greater than threshold using `apply` and use it to extract the rows from `mat` data.

```
mat[apply( mat2, 1, function( x ) any( x > threshold ) ), ]
```

**EDIT:**

Break down of the above single line.

```
# create sample data by simulating samples from standard normal distribution
set.seed(1L)   # set random number generator for consistent data simulation

mat <- matrix( data = c(letters[1:3], as.character( rnorm(9, mean = 0, sd = 1))),
               byrow = FALSE, 
               nrow = 3, 
               ncol = 4 ) # create simulated data matrix

threshold <- 0  # set threshold

mat2 <- apply( mat[, 2:ncol(mat) ], 2, as.numeric )  # extract columns 2 to end and convert to numeric

# Get the logical indices (true or false) if any row has values greater than 0 (threshold)
row_indices <- apply( mat2, 1, function( x ) any( x > threshold ) )

mat[row_indices, ]  # extract matrix data rows that has TRUE in row_indices
#     [,1]                 [,2]                 [,3]                 [,4]               
# [1,] "a"  "-0.626453810742332" "1.59528080213779"   "0.487429052428485"
# [2,] "b"  "0.183643324222082"  "0.329507771815361"  "0.738324705129217"
# [3,] "c"  "-0.835628612410047" "-0.820468384118015" "0.575781351653492"
```

**Note:**

In your question, you mentioned that first column is character and the rest are numbers. By rule, matrix can hold one data type. Given this information, I assume that your data matrix is a character data type. You can find it by using `class(mat)`. If it is character matrix, then extract columns 2 to end and then convert it to numeric. Then use it in the apply loop to check for any values greater than threshold.

Comment: I can confirm that does work!  I'm hoping I'm not asking too much, but can you break down this statement to explain how it works?  Even after looking at the help page for the apply function, I can't seem to understand what you're doing.  Thank you!

Comment: if you have `apply(data, 1, function)` then you are looping by rows. If you have `apply(data, 2, function)` then you are looping by column. The second argument `MARGIN` determines whether you want to loop by rows or columns. Hope this helps

Comment: Wow!  Thanks so much for such a detailed explanation!  And yes, I see now [finally] what you mean about matrix holding one data type.  In my case, the "first column" was the row name.  Clearly I didn't quite understand the matrix data type.  Nevertheless, instead of asking me to re-edit my question, you gave me a working solution.  Thank you for this!  Now that I see what you mean, I'll go back and clarify my question a bit better for others.  Thanks again for your help!!